# How to get Apache and MySQL logs in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I would like to get Apache and MySQL logs in my PHP script like:

```
echo(file_get_contents('/var/log/apache2/error.log'));
echo(file_get_contents('/var/log/mysql/error.log'));
```

and clear after that:

```
file_put_contents('/var/log/mysql/error.log','');
```

but none of this works

Probably some conflict of access rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your username to the group adm
**(sudo usermod -aG adm YourUserName)**

```
<?php   
    echo shell_exec('tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log');

?>

or

<?php
$op = array();
exec('tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log', $op, $stat);
print_r($op);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you it work! (after sudo usermod -aG adm www-data)